# Jquery associate two arrays (key, value) into one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associations, mootools

How can I associate two arrays that contains keys and values into one array with key->value pairs?

In Mootools there is `associate` function which does:

```
var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
sounds.associate(animals);
// returns {'Cow': 'Moo', 'Pig': 'Oink', 'Dog': 'Woof', 'Cat': 'Miao'}
```

Is there any similar function in JQuery to obtain the same result from those two arrays?

If not, how can I do it?

Comment: MooTools has much more non-DOM methods than jQuery. You could use MooTools instead of jQuery... then you have all DOM methods from MooTools, plus the extra sugar like this `.associate()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't really have associative arrays, but you can use an object instead.

```
Array.prototype.associate = function (keys) {
  var result = {};

  this.forEach(function (el, i) {
    result[keys[i]] = el;
  });

  return result;
};

var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
console.dir(sounds.associate(animals));
```

Comment: if i have a duplicate values in animals array and i want to append this value with previous (let say in Array) value, it returns a number instead of value. var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cow'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    values = [1, 2, 3],
    associated = keys.reduce(function (previous, key, index) {
        previous[key] = values[index];
        return previous
    }, {})

console.log(associated) // Object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

[reduce is not supported natively on IE<9](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.reduce) but you can safely use the [Polyfill on the mdn site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill)
which you can include using a conditional comment to target ie <9 only.

If you want a reusable function is pretty straightforward to do:

```
function associate(keys, values){
    return keys.reduce(function (previous, key, index) {
        previous[key] = values[index];
        return previous
    }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not jQuery, but simple enough to be achieved with pure JS (here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tBxx/)):

```
var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
var assoc = [];
for(var i=0; i<animals.length; i++) {
    assoc[animals[i]] = sounds[i];
}
console.log(assoc);
```

prints:

```
Cat: "Miao"
Cow: "Moo"
Dog: "Woof"
Pig: "Oink"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own similar to this:

```
Array.prototype.associate = function(arr){
    var index,
        output = Object.create(null);

    for(index = 0; index < this.length; index++){
        output[arr[index]] = this[index];
    }

    return output;
};
```

Then you can use it as expected, similar to this:

```
var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
var x = sounds.associate(animals);
```

The result in `x` is `{'Cow': 'Moo', 'Pig': 'Oink', 'Dog': 'Woof', 'Cat': 'Miao'}`

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/d5R5a/) - Replicating Mootool's associate function

---

Answer (score 0):

you can use in java scipt.

```
Array.prototype.associate= function(){
 var that = this;
 var associated ={};
 var len = that.length;
 for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
    associated[that[i]] = value[i];
 }
 return associated;
 } 
var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
console.log(animals.associate(sounds));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a dependency like *lodash* to your project, then it's as easy as:

```
let result = _.zip([key1, key2], [value1, value2])
```

This will produce a new array of arrays:

```
[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]
```

To the result, apply the lodash function *fromPairs*:

```
let finalResult = _.fromPairs(resultArrayFromPreviousCode)
```

finalResult is now:

```
{ key1: value1, key2: value2 }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### for...of Method

You can also use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement in conjunction with [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) to create an object using one array for keys and another for values:

```js
const array_combine = (keys, values) => {
  const result = {};
  
  for (const [index, key] of keys.entries()) {
    result[key] = values[index];
  }
  
  return result;
};

const animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
const sounds  = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];

console.log(array_combine(animals, sounds));
```